# How do I use OpenAPI for aws_api_gateway_rest_api

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, openapi

I'm trying to use OpenAPI because it looks like a standard and it's less cumbersome than terraform resources. I've converted json to what terraform might take but I get the error:

```
module.aws_api_gateway.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.CICDAPI: body must be a single value, not a list
```

Bellow is my code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "CICDAPI" {
  name        = "cicdapi"
  description = "cicd build pipeline"
  binary_media_types = [
    "application/json"
  ]

  body = {
      swagger = 2
      info {
        title = "AwsServerlessExpressApi"
      }
      basePath = "/prod"
      schemes = [
        "https"
      ]
   ....
```

I've yet to find an example on how we can assign OpenAPI to aws gateway api resource. Can I just make body a json string??? It's not said anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see by the error it needs to be a string rather than a hashmap like you have in your code.

You should be able to simply wrap the body value in a [heredoc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html#terraform-syntax).

So you want something like:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "CICDAPI" {
  name        = "cicdapi"
  description = "cicd build pipeline"
  binary_media_types = [
    "application/json"
  ]

  body = <<EOF
{
  swagger = 2
  info {
    title = "AwsServerlessExpressApi"
  }
  basePath = "/prod"
  schemes = [
    "https"
  ]
 ....
}
EOF
}
```

The docs are lacking for explaining this but you can also see how it's implemented in the [acceptance test](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/1197/files#diff-391e2cdf16e81800eef7b320c77a3268R223).

I'd also need to check this but I think you can probably load your OpenAPI spec from a file by using `body = "${file("path/to/file")}"`